# Disable profile field when module that created it is disabled?

Tags: entities, installation

I have created a module that adds a field to the user profile. When I disable the module, I want the field to no longer be shown on the user profile. I do not want to wipe it out completely, since I do that on uninstall. I want it to come back with the original data when the module is reenabled I just want to have it not display when the module is disabled. Is there a way to do this? I am using Drupal 7 and the field is a text field and it is set to the default formatter when I create the instance. Is there a setting I can set the instance to in hook_uninstall that will hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to accomplish it through code by setting the field instance:

```
    'display'       => array
      'default'     => array(
        'label'     => 'above',
        'type'      => 'hidden',
        'weight'    => '1',
        'settings'  => array(),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to do something with your theme in order to hide the filed. Obviously you can't use your module, as it is disabled. You could do a check with [module_exists](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_exists/7) to see if the module is installed, and if it is, print the info, if not, ignore it.